# marque html javascript dosent get affect on realtime

Tags: javascript, html

I used javscript to change marque direction left or right and also I change its speed 
but it didnt change its speed or direction unless it had finished scrolling all text inside it 
is there way to solve this ?

```
//change Marquee to right
document.getElementById('myMarquee').direction = "right";

//change Marquee to left
document.getElementById('myMarquee').direction = "left";
```

I used listener on it i see it on console its change the attr but didnt change on browser just when finished scrolling text

Comment: You want it to continue from where it was (i.e. if text was in the middle when it was changed go from the middle), or start from fresh on change?

Comment: What is it that you are doing by using marquee? There may be a better solution.

Comment: yes continue from where it was 
ex : its on the middle and i change its direction its continue but with new direction

Comment: @Popnoodles what the better sloution ?  slider ?

Comment: .....What is it that you are doing by using marquee?

Comment: i use it as so simple slider

Comment: Ok. Simple answer. Find a slider that works for you.

Comment: I just realised that you can remove and replace the marquee to have it change direction, but you would need to work out the position of the text. It's still going to be easier to control by not using marquee.